# Spring multi-language

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm new working with Spring MVC and I have some problems to add multi language to my application.

I dont' use xml configuration. I have a @Configuration class

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.springexamples.basic.controller")
public class BasicServletConfig extends BaseConfig {

    @Bean
    ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        return getViewResolver("views/basic/", ".jsp");
    }

    @Bean
    MessageSource messageSource() {
        return getMessageSource("/messages/messages");
}

@Bean
LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return interceptor;
}

@Bean
LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    return new SessionLocaleResolver();
}

@Bean
HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setInterceptors(new HandlerInterceptor[] { localeChangeInterceptor() });
    return mapping;
}
}
```

When I test de application always I see the default language (spanish). I send the request with the parameter 'lang=en' or 'lang=EN' but I still see it in default language.

¿Anyone knows the solution?.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show the code for `BaseConfig.getMessageSource()` as `BaseConfig` is not a standard spring class.

Comment: 'code'
 protected ViewResolver getViewResolver(String prefix, String suffix) {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix(prefix);
  resolver.setSuffix(suffix);
  return resolver;
 }
 
 protected MessageSource getMessageSource(String messageFile) {
  ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
  messageSource.setBasename(messageFile);
  messageSource.setCacheSeconds(15);
  return messageSource;
 }
}

Comment: I put these code in other class because I will use the same code for diferent Configuration. (I hate write the same thing twice :D)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `HandlerMapping` declared this way will play with `@EnableWebMvc`. A more idiomatic way to configure interceptors with `@EnableWebMvc` is to use `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc 
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.springexamples.basic.controller") 
public class BasicServletConfig extends BaseConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi,
   First of all thanks for the quick answer. I have implemented 'WebMvcConfigurer' and I have configured 'addInterceptors' (only) like you write, but It still doesn't work.

Comment: hi axtavt, i also tried to use __WebMvcConfigure__ Interface. but for me also it is not working :(